# sequelize where greater than using average column from attributes

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I want to filter the data to only "avgRate" greater than 4, but when I use this code its returns error "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'items.avgRate' in 'on clause'", this is my code

```js
Items.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Reviews,
      attributes: [],
    },
  ],
  attributes: {
    include: [[Sequelize.fn('avg', Sequelize.col('reviews.star')), 'avgRate']],
  },
  group: ['id'],
  where: {
    avgRate: {
      [Op.gt]: 4.5,
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: you can't use calculated column in WHERE clause.

Comment: is there any ways to filter the items based on avgRate?

Comment: Usually in plain SQL query this can be achieved using `HAVING` clause along with GROUP BY and Sequelize does not have such option. Sequelize wasn't developed as a tool to execute complex aggregating queries so it's better to use plain SQL query for such queries.

Comment: yes, `having` exists in Sequelize. `having: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col('avgRate'), Op.gt, 4.5)` 

https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-findAll